# Is there any way to change the Item Route before you reach the 10th Floor Innocent town?

Tags: disgaea-5

I am mostly using the Item world to subdue Innocents for now. I am moving Innocents I want into Items I want to level up. But I cannot find a way to change the Route to Innocent Enhance before I get to the 10th floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would just skip through the floors and/or use a diver-10.  This isn't a big deal, because you can go past Floor 100.  The only limit I've seen is you can only get to item level 500, until you beat the last Carnage Challenge map (that lets you level up items past 500).